# How to draw coins in a path with patterns in superjumper game?

Tags: android, libgdx

How can I place coins in SuperJumper game because right now coins are being drawn randomly but I want to draw in particular patterns like circle, half circle, and straight line. Here's the code I have so far-

```
 int coinecoord = rand.nextInt(3);
        switch(coinecoord)
        {
            case 0:
                if (rand.nextFloat() > 0.5f)
                {

                    Coin coin = new Coin(x1 +1, y + Coin.COIN_HEIGHT + rand.nextFloat() * 3,0);
                    coins.add(coin);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (rand.nextFloat() > 0.5f)
                {

                    Coin coin = new Coin(x1 +6, y + Coin.COIN_HEIGHT + rand.nextFloat() * 3,1);
                    coins.add(coin);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (rand.nextFloat() > 0.5f)
                {

                    Coin coin = new Coin(x1 +rand.nextFloat(), y + Coin.COIN_HEIGHT + rand.nextFloat() * 3,2);
                    coins.add(coin);
                }
                break;
        }

        y += (maxJumpHeight - 0.5f) /3.0f;// add plateform
        y -= rand.nextFloat() * (maxJumpHeight / 3);
    }
```

draw in world Renderer class as---

```
private void renderItems()
{
    int len = world.springs.size();

    len = world.coins.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Coin coin = world.coins.get(i);
        TextureRegion keyFrame;
        //System.out.println("coin.getMoreCoin()"+coin.getMoreCoin());
        switch (coin.getMoreCoin())
        {
        case 0:
            keyFrame = Assets.coinAnim.getKeyFrame(coin.stateTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            batch.draw(keyFrame, coin.position.x - 0.5f, coin.position.y - 0.8f, 1, 1.6f);
            break;
        case 1:
            keyFrame = Assets.coinAnim.getKeyFrame(coin.stateTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            batch.draw(keyFrame, coin.position.x - 0.5f, coin.position.y - 0.8f, 1, 1.6f);
            break;
        case 2:
            keyFrame = Assets.coinAnim.getKeyFrame(coin.stateTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            batch.draw(keyFrame, coin.position.x - 0.5f, coin.position.y - 0.8f, 1, 1.6f);
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

please anyone assist me...

Answer (score 2):

You can have an imaginary grid say 8 by 8. Hence, 64 cells meaning 64 coins. Initially, you can set the visibility of the coins to false(In your coin class, you can have another property say visibility which will be initially set to false). You can create some nice patterns of how coin should appear by making some cells visible and invisible. For each pattern, you might want a coin in a particular cell to be visible and some cells to be invisible. In your render method, show the coins which are set to visible.